# meteor deployed but some package uncaught

Tags: meteor

i have a meteor application, with this package :

```
meteor-platform
insecure
iron:router
aslagle:reactive-table
accounts-base
accounts-password
natestrauser:font-awesome
mizzao:bootboxjs
aldeed:autoform
aldeed:simple-schema
aldeed:collection2
matb33:collection-hooks
twbs:bootstrap
```

when it still in development, it run well. but when i deploy by bundled, i have this error :

[image: Some packages uncaught error]

Why this happend? and how to solve it?

Comment: if you want to reproduce this error in local try "meteor run --production", it will bundle your app and run it just like production

Comment: looks like the issue is somewhere in your app you're using `{{> reactiveTable}}` but that template is not available in any packages or in your code

Comment: @Sasikanth thanks for response, i have run "meteor run --production" but  i dont get this error, {{>reactiveTable}} from package aslagle:reactive-table